# Is it bad design to expect the client to cast between interfaces?

Tags: design, object-oriented

Is it bad design to expect the client to cast between interfaces? I understand it can be done, but is it clean? I'm comparing retirement profiles in a simulation. I have 2 different types of TSPs (think 401k). I have a TSP class, which holds employee contributions (no government match). MatchingTSP is a TSP, but it also includes government matching contributions. Looking specifically at this case:

**--MY DOMAIN MODEL--**

```
interface ITSP
{
  public void MakeContribution(...);
  public double CalculateContributionByYear(int year);
  public double CalculateCumulativeContributions(...);
  public double CalculateTotal(...);
}

class TSP : public ITSP
{
  public virtual void MakeContribution(...) {...}
  public virtual double CalculateContributionByYear(int year) {...}
  public virtual double CalculateCumulativeContributions(...) {...}
  public virtual double CalculateTotal(...) {...}

  private IList<TSPContribution> contributions;
}

interface IMatchableTSP
{
  public void MakeContribution(...);
  public double CalculateContributionByYear(int year);
  public double CalculateCumulativeContributions(...);
  public double CalculateTotal(...);
}

class MatchableTSP : public TSP, IMatchableTSP
{
  public override void MakeContribution(...) {...}
  public override CalculateContributionByYear(int year) {...}
  public override CalculateCumulativeContributions(...) {...}
  public override CalculateTotal(...) {...}

  private IList<TSPContribution> contributions;
}
```

**--CLIENT USE--**

```
ITSP johnTSP = TSPFactory.CreateTSP();
ITSP jimTSP = TSPFactory.CreateMatchableTSP();

// Print BaseTSP Employee Contributions
Console.WriteLine(johnTSP.CalculateCumulativeContributions());
Console.WriteLine(jim.TSP.CalculateCumulativeContributions());

// Print MatchingTSP Contributions
Console.WriteLine((IMatchableTSP)jim.TSP.CalculateCumulativeContributions());
```

So I see two problems here:  the client needs to cast between different interfaces to get different types of data.  The interfaces are duplicated (violating DRY) to allow this casting between interfaces.

Should I use casting to get the different data that I want (e.g. employee contributions vs government matching contributions) or should I add new methods in MatchingTSP that include MakeMatchingContribution(...), CalculateMatchingContributionByYear(int year), etc.

Comment: So I'm guessing the factory method `CreateMatchableTSP` doesn't return an `IMatchableTSP`.  Why is that?  Also, it seems like `IMatchableTSP` should just inherit from `ITSP`.  Is there a reason it doesn't?  (Also, not quite sure what language you are using, so that might explain why you can't do some of the things I'm thinking you should be able to.)

Comment: IMatchableTPS could just inherit from ITSP like a marker interface (and probably makes most sense).  Factory.Createxxxx methods can return either.  This was more of a design question, is it clean for clients to cast to different interfaces to get the data they need?

Comment: Functionally, what is the difference between `MatchableTSP` and plain ol' `TSP`?  All your interfaces and implementations look identical.

Comment: @MetaFight, I'm comparing retirement profiles in a simulation.  I have 2 different types of TSPs (think 401k).  I have TSP which is just an employee putting in contributions (no government match).  MatchingTSP is a TSP, but it also includes government matching contributions.

Comment: Added to the question for clarity.

Comment: @MetaFight, I need to keep track of employee contributions vs employee + matching contributions.  Even with the MatchingTSP, I also want to track the employee's contributions in addition to what the government matched.

Comment: I think you're modelling this incorrectly.  You're describing two TSPs.  They don't need distinct *types* to differentiate them.  They only need to be different *instances*.

Comment: @MetaFight, I could see that.  But how do I differentiate between Employee and Matching contributions?

Comment: That would be handled higher up in your object graph.  What is holding the reference to your TSP?

Comment: @MetaFight, an employee object.  I would prefer to use a Rich Domain model and push logic down in the objects (vice an Anemic Domain model).  It is my understanding and preference that the TSP object should know how to calculate itself.

Comment: I don't know much about your domain, but you could still accomplish this with a rich Domain Model.  Your employee makes a TSP contribution.  This generates a Domain Event.  Other entities can subscribe to this event.  Eg, an Employer is notified of the contribution and it reacts by making a matching contribution.  Here, "Matching contribution" is modelled as a "Process" (sometime called a Saga).

Comment: @MetaFight, that makes sense. Where do you advocate tracking matching vs employee contributions?  They’re two separate collections I need to track to report back to the user.

Comment: I don't know what your Domain Model looks like, so it's hard to comment.

Comment: COM works kinda like this but the "casting" (retrieval) of a specific interface is generalized. In that case you query what interfaces an object has in order to figure out what you can do with it. "Does this object provide a motion interface? If yes, move it. If no, skip to the next one." I personally found ECS codebases easier to maintain but that also sort of depends on casting, except it's asking, "Does this entity *have* a move component? If so, modify the component to move the entity."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use casting to get the different data that I want

**No.** Using the same name for two different methods that do different things can't be a good idea. Using the same name for two different methods that return different data, where both methods can both be implemented by the same object, is bound to cause confusion.

> should I add new methods in MatchingTSP

**Yes.** There's no reason not to create new methods for the additional tasks that are involved in conforming to `IMatchableTSP`. Just doing that will make life less confusing for people using your interfaces, and you can probably avoid a whole class of confusion-related bugs just by choosing clear names.